# Not able to Restore MS SQL server database using Cloudberry. Getting Error: Invalid value specified for STOPAT parameter

Tags: sql-server, cloudberry

I have the backup generated through cloudberry(Application) at Amazon AWS S3 storage.The bucket in S3 has region specified as Asia Pacific(Sydney). Backups are generating on recurring basis with transaction log backup once in every 2 hour.

The same backup file i am restoring using cloud berry but getting the error. I am specifying Point in time restore in cloudberry plan setup.Error i am getting is like :  "Invalid value specified for STOPAT parameter.RESTORE LOG is terminating abnormally"

the server is in Australia itself, And Date and time zone of server is GMT+10. 
the date format of server at d/MM/yyyy.SQL server-2005 language is set to "British English".Its my production server so without exact solution i cant implement changes there.I tried to replicate that issue with same configuration of OS but not able to do so.

what i need to do to solve this issue or what kind of parameter i need to change to resolve this?

Comment: Check what the *actual* restore command looks like and post it. `STOPAT` means you tried to perform a point-in-time restore. Did you really want to do that?

Comment: The error complains about the format of the time parameter's *format*, not the timezone. To avoid such problems always use unambiguous formats, like the ISO8601 format or the unseparated date format. How did you enter the time? As a string? Selected from a date picker? Does the tool have any locale settings?

Comment: Tool uses the locale seeting of time and date. I cant see the restore command in that tool its just a UI in which i need to specify the database file to restore. i followed the same steps in below blog.

https://www.cloudberrylab.com/blog/backup-and-restore-of-sql-server-databases/